# Multiplicative order in field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F/K$ be some field extension (both are finite fields) and $u$ be some element in $F$.

I want to know if $u^{|K|} = u$ implies $u \in K$. And why?

Comment: The polynomial $x^{|K|} - x$ has at most $|K|$ roots.

Comment: @Hurkyl:  why not post your thoughts as an answer and get some rep?  That helps MSE as well, for there is a *gigantic* pile-up of unanswered questions!  Regards, RKL

Comment: @robert: Mainly because I'm not inclined to spend the time writing up a proper answer at the moment, so I'm happy to just kick things off and let someone else score the rep (and hopefully say the things I'm too lazy to talk about right now).

Comment: @Hurkyl:  yeah, I know how you feel about that, I wish I could get paid for the time I spend writing up answers on MSE! ;-)! Gracious of you, thanks.  Maybe I will . . . in my *utterly copious* free time!

Comment: @Hurkyl:  If I had $3.5 \times 10^4 +$ in rep I probably would feel too lazy to answer myself! ;-) Cheers, RKL

Answer (score 1):

As $K^*$ is a group of order $|K|-1$ (under multiplication) every element there satisfies the equation 
$x^{|K|-1}=1$. So multiplying by $x$, these elements along with $0$, satisfy the equation $x^{|K|}-x=0$. As equations over fields cannot have more roots than the degree it is not possible for elements of the extension field $F$ (not in $K$)  to be the root of that equation.  This is the argument Hurkyl had in her/his mind and  did not have the time write up.